# Bash script runs fine, but not in cron

Tags: 14.04, bash, vlc, cron, lame

I have a script that's supposed to record a shoutcast stream for an hour, convert it to mp3, and then save it. The script runs correctly when I run it from the terminal, but I can't seem to get it to run in cron (where it should run every hour at the top of the hour).

Here's the line in crontab:

```
0 * * * * /medialib/tech/bin/recordstream 2>&1 >> /medialib/tech/cron.log
```

and here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="$(date +%s)"

mp3_name=$name.mp3
wav_name=$name.wav

timeout -sHUP 60m vlc -I dummy --sout "#transcode{channels=2}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=/medialib/stream_backup/wav/$wav_name" /medialib/tech/lib/listen.m3u

lame --mp3input /medialib/stream_backup/wav/$wav_name /medialib/stream_backup/$mp3_name

rm /medialib/stream_backup/wav/$wav_name
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Contents of cron.log (This text has been in the log file since it was transferred from an old server where it was working).

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> Shutting down.
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> Shutting down.
```

Comment: "for an hour" + "0 * * * *"  this runs on the hour every hour. I see nothing wrong besides the "rm". You should add something to avoid confirmation (`--force`)

Comment: In addition to @Rinzwind's point, my crontab has an additional column between the time and command for the user to run the command under.  You might try adjusting your crontab to
`0 * * * * root /medialib/tech/bin/recordstream 2>&1 >> /medialib/tech/cron.log`  I suppose that depends on whether this is `/etc/crontab` or your user crontab.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably fixing that at the same time you were commenting :P

Comment: Do you have any message in `cron.log`?

Comment: I don't think your redirect is working properly. move `2>&1` to the end of the command, then maybe you can get an error message in the logfile.

Comment: @dan08 that seemed to solve it. I'll confirm when it kicks off at noon. Thanks!

Comment: @dan08 that solved it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to see if cron is running

```
ps -ef | grep cron
```

If it is not running, start it as root

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron start (Ubuntu and Red Hat).
```

Secondly, check the permissions of the script, if it have the "x" option and then try to run

```
crontab -e
```

Try to see if the cron you made is listed with this command

```
crontab -l
```

EDIT:

Try to add /bin/bash right before your script call :

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash /script/file
```

Any more clues to solve it [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/a-short-introduction-to-cron-jobs).

Comment: Tried running through each of these. Cron is running (as root). Permissions on the script are (until I figure this out) 777. It is listed when I run crontab -e.

Comment: When you run it by command line, the log shows the output normally?

Comment: @radiotech edited answer, see if this works